# Disk Encryption cryptsetup, Failed to initialize device signature probes. Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters)

Tags: encryption

```
sudo cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb1
```

brings up the following error:

```
Failed to initialize device signature probes.
```

Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).